# image not loading on web page

Tags: javascript, carousel, glidejs

this is the js code

```
if(slider2){
    new Glide(slider2, {
        type:'carousel',
        startAt: 0,
        hoverpause:true,
        preview: 4,
        animationDuration: 800,
        animationTimingFunc: 'cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.44, 0.1)',
        breakpoints:{
            1200:{
                preview: 3,
            },
            768:{
                preview: 2,
            },
        },
    }).mount();
}
```

Comment: What are we supposed to do with that? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: the code is below

Comment: The code you've provided is insufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do I make the check sufficient to produce the problem? I really need a solution

Comment: Read the links in my first comment.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at your inspector and look at the slides styles.

Your issue might be related to glide giving your slides a ridiculously large transform value. Its the same issue I am currently experiencing and still looking for a solution.

But I too initially thought that is just wasn't loading when it was actually just off screen

EDIT:
It's also mentioned on glideJS github : https://github.com/glidejs/glide/issues/654

Adding image for reference to what I mean:
I cant add images but here are image links

**Element**

[image]

**Styles Inspector**

[image]